Strange activity of my system
Linux dell 6.8.0-45-generic #45-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Fri Aug 30 12:02:04 UTC 2024 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
Please check the following screen shots and let me know my system is hacked or not?

This screen shot is taken with wifi

This screen shot is taken without wifi
Say if hacked what should I do in this regards
Best regards

If you are at all concerned about security Install GUFW (graphic version of Uncomplicated Fire EWall): sudo apt install gufw -y See also this Ubuntu Community post for further information.

Thanks for your reply

Please add information, what makes you think that you may have been hacked. From your screenshots there is no evidence for that.

I was thinking kworker is perhaps doing bad things
